# How can I remove Child2 by parent using js

Tags: javascript

I was going to remove Child2 by parent, but its doesn't work

```
var y = document.getElementById('parent');
y.childNodes[0].removeChild(y.childNodes[0].childNodes[2]);

<div id="parent">
    <div>
        <a href="#">First</a>
        <a href="#">second</a>
        <a href="#">third</a> <!--I wanna delete this-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Its just doesn't delete anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `children` instead of `childNodes`, because `childNodes` includes other element types whereas `children` is just elements.

**[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes#Notes):**

> `childNodes` includes all child nodes, including non-element nodes like text and comment nodes. To get a collection of only elements, use [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead.

You can also use [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) instead of `removeChild()` which will remove the current element from the dom.

```js
var y = document.getElementById('parent');
y.children[0].children[2].remove();
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div>
        <a href="#">First</a>
        <a href="#">second</a>
        <a href="#">third</a> <!--I wanna delete this-->
    </div>
</div>
```